# Access camera and photo information via javascript, or ANY other language?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, android-camera

when an image is taken, information such as;

- Date taken
- Camera
- Lens
- Focal Length
- Exposure
- F Number
- ISO
- Camera make
- Flash(if used or not)
- Exposure Bias e.t.c

is at times written within the image and can actually be retrieved for further usage.
a live example is what [Google plus does](https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts?pid=6173274135056727234&oid=102150693225130002912) (you can see the screen shot below), if you are a chronic [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com) fan, you might notice that tumblr   is capable of that too. Now, how the do they do it? 
[image: camera and photo information]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is available within the photo file as so-called "Exif data". You can learn more about how this works on this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format

An example implementation in JavaScript is https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js