# Prevent Virtual/Fake camera from loading?

Tags: javascript, camera, virtualization

I've been searching for 6 days this topic, all over the net, i have asked in all the forums i'm in.. someone said they could do it for $200..

I have a website that loads a users webcam and allows a screencap/picture, then uploads to my server.

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='https://gatekeeper.killaxia.com/getimage.php'>";
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='col-md-6'>";
        echo "<div id='my_camera'></div>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<input
              type='button'
              value='Take Snapshot'
              onClick='take_snapshot()'
            />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='image' class='image-tag' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='userid' value=$uid />";
            echo "</div>";
```

Then loads the camera like so

```
<script language="JavaScript">
      Webcam.set({
        width: 490,
        height: 390,
        image_format: "jpeg",
        jpeg_quality: 100,
      });
 
      Webcam.attach("#my_camera");
 
      function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
          $(".image-tag").val(data_uri);
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =
            '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Is it possible to check the camera source to see if its fake/virtual? I know omegle.com can detect it, they either still say or used to say "the stranger may be using a fake video" etc.. so yes its possible.

ANY HELP?

My project is dead until this is working, no fake camera!

Comment: Maybe by checking the lens inoformation like: Iso, shutterspeed, focal length, ...

Comment: I have no idea how to go about doing that.. i didn't even honestly think about that, any docs on this?

Comment: I do not know how accurate this methode is (how many fals positives and false negatives) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207525/access-camera-and-photo-information-via-javascript-or-any-other-language

Comment: i might be able to compile a list of "camera makes" and error if it isnt in my list

Comment: Will be hard, somme fake camera software can be renamed to sommething not in the list.